# How can i execute code for a specific amount of time in java?

Tags: java, events, execution

I'd like to execute some code for, let's say 5 seconds, inside of a method that listens for events.
I've tried to use Threads but wasn't able to make it work properly.

This is my code for now, it's just a listener that triggers when a message with the string in the if statement is detected:

```java
if (message != null){
            if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("w")){

            }
        }
```

this check is ran every second so i don't know if "while" statements could work

Comment: Share us with the code you've tried and the problems you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trivial approach would be to simply execute your code in a loop and check in each iteration whether your timing-threshold was reached, such as:

```
// necessary imports for using classes Instant and Duration.
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.Duration;

// ...

// start time point of your code execution.
Instant start = Instant.now();

// targeted duration of your code execution (e.g. 5 sec.).
Duration duration = Duration.ofSeconds(5);
     
// loop your code execution and test in each iteration whether you reached your duration threshold.
while (Duration.between(start, Instant.now()).toMillis() <= duration.toMillis())
{
    // execute your code here ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea not for deployment but should give you an starting point

```
//record start time
long start=System.currentTimeMillis();

//keep running until 5000ms[5s] have 
//elapsed since the start
while(System.currentTimeMillis()-start<=5000)
{
 //Do some stuff here
}
```

If your event handler is executed in the same thread as your system then this will block your system for 5 seconds and stop it from handling other events during that duration.

So its better to dispatch your events to seperate threads or execute the above logic in a seperate thread